# Как скомпилировать игру на unity для PC в заданном разрешении

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

подскажите как можно скомпилировать игры для PC на UNity и при этом выбирать в каком формате или разрешении компилировать.И чтобы не растягивало на весь экран а оставались черные полосы по бокам или сверху и снизу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 1]

В прошлых версиях Unity можно было перейти в Project Settings/Player и установить нужное разрешение и другие параметры изображения.

Более подробнее можете посмотреть тут: http://www.aclockworkberry.com/managing-screen-resolution-and-aspect-ratio-in-unity-3d/